# Why is the .getElementsByClassName returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to make a Chrome extension for chess.com. I am trying to access the chess move list using .getElementsByClassName. The issue is that the .getElementsByClassName is returning undefined and I'm not sure why.

Here is my code for my contentscript.js.

```
let moveList;
function getChessMove() {
    moveList = document.getElementsByClassName("white node")[0].textContent;
    console.log(moveList);
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(getChessMove());
```

When I plug the .getElementsByClassName into the console on chess.com, it returns the correct text, which in this case is 'e4'.

[image: console of chess.com showing .getElemtentsByClassName returning 'e4']

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is. I've tried using a for loop, but then it doens't print anything into the console.

```
let moveList;
function getChessMove() {
    moveList = document.getElementsByClassName("white node");
    for (i = 0; i < moveList.length; i++) {
        console.log(moveList[i].textContent);
    } 
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(getChessMove());
```

I'm not sure what to do with this, if it helps here is my background.js file as well, which send a message to my content script file when chess.com tab is present.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {
  if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("chess.com/game/")) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
      message: "chess tab"
    })
  }
})
```

I've also tried using .querySelector but that just returns null.

```
let moveList;
function getChessMove() {
    moveList = document.querySelector('.white.node');
    console.log(moveList);
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(getChessMove());
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Are you waiting until the DOM is ready before performing the query? I'm not sure when `chrome.runtime.onMessage` fires.

Comment: Remove `()` from your addListener line.